# Null measure set and integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $f,g:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be integrable functions and $$X=\{x \in [a,b];f(x) \ne g(x)\}$$
be a set with zero measure.

Prove that $$\int_a^b f(x)dx=\int_a^b g(x)dx$$ and show two functions $f \ne g$ such that $X$ is infinite and has zero measure.

How can i do this in a context of Riemann integration? I saw some answers in other questions but it wasn't very helpful.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by a set of measure zero in the context of Riemann integration?

Comment: Which other questions? Why were the answers unhelpful? Did they use tools you don't have access to? In order not to just give you the same unhelpful answers again, we need to know what was unhelpful about these answers.

Comment: I saw some anserws using measure theory, but i'm learning this im real analysis. One of those was https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73859/measure-zero-set-as-the-set-of-discontinuities-of-a-function-integrals

Comment: Then how is a 'set with zero measure' defined?

Comment: We are using the "commom" definition, i guess, $X \in \mathbb{R}$ has null (or zero?) measure if, for all $\epsilon>0$, there is a finite or infite covering $X\subset \cup I_k$ with $\sum I_k < \epsilon$

Comment: @ask1234 perhaps you will find this question to be useful https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4028194/232754

Answer (score 7):

We can prove this in the context of Riemann integration just using one measure-related fact: the measure of a non-empty interval is positive.

If $f$ and $g$ are Riemann integrable, then so is $h := f-g$ and $X = \{x \in [a,b]:h(x) \neq 0\}$ is given to be of measure zero.

For any partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots <x_n = b $, each subinterval $I_j = [x_{j-1},x_j]$ has positive measure and, hence, there is a point $x \in I_j$ where $h(x) = 0$.  This implies that $\inf_{x \in I_j} h(x) \leqslant 0 \leqslant \sup_{x \in I_j} h(x)$ and, consequently for upper and lower Darboux sums we have

$$\tag{1}L(P,h) \leqslant 0 \leqslant U(P,h)$$

Since $h$ is Riemann integrable we have for all $P$,

$$\tag{2}L(P,h) \leqslant \int_a^b h(x) \, dx \leqslant U(P,h)$$

and for any $\epsilon >0$, there exists a partition $P_\epsilon$ where $U(P_\epsilon,h) - L(P_\epsilon,h) < \epsilon$

In view of   (1) and (2) this implies that

$$-\epsilon < -(U(P_\epsilon,h) - L(P_\epsilon,h)) \leqslant \int_a^bh(x) \,dx \leqslant U(P_\epsilon,h) - L(P_\epsilon,h) < \epsilon$$

Since $\epsilon$ can be arbitrarily close to zero, it follows that

$$\int_a^bf(x) \, dx - \int_a^b g(x) \, dx = \int_a^bh(x) \,dx = 0$$

Comment: Thank you! But, if u can explain me why we have: " or any partition $P: a = x_0 < x_1 < \ldots <x_n = b$, each subinterval $I_j=[x_{j−1},x_j]$ has positive measure and, hence, there is a point $x \in I_j$ where $h(x)=0.$ i will be grateful

Comment: @ask1234: We can't have the compact interval $I_j$ contained in $X$ otherwise it could be contained in the union of a finite collection of open intervals $J_1,\ldots,J_n$ of total length less than $\epsilon < l(I_j) = x_j - x_{j-1}$. So there must always be a point $x \in I_j$ and $x \not\in X$ where $h(x) = 0$..

Comment: Get it! Thank you!